# OpenAPI - add a security scheme to require authorization for my api

Tags: node.js, openapi, swagger-ui-express

How can I define the security scheme and apply the authorization to my endpoint(s)?

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.0.3",
    "info": {
        "description": "NodeJS API documentation of SSV",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "SSV APIs"
    },
    "components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
            "BearerAuth": {
                "name": "Authorization",
                "in": "header",
                "type": "apiKey",
                "scheme": "bearer",
                "bearerFormat": "JWT",
                "description": "Enter your bearer token in the format Bearer <token>"
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

```js
import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";
import openapiSpecification from "../swaggerAPI";

const options = {
    explorer: true,
  };

app.use(
    "/api-docs",
    swaggerUi.serve,
    swaggerUi.setup(openapiSpecification, options)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things with your description.

`"swagger": "2.0"` has a completely different structure than the one used. You should define `"openapi": "3.0.3"` to match your file content.

Adding the `security` array at the root of the file will require the authorization for all endpoints defined.

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.0.3",
    "info": {
        "description": "NodeJS API documentation of SSV",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "SSV APIs"
    },
    "security": [
        {
            "BearerAuth": []
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/thing": {
            "get": {
                "description": "Get all things",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
            "BearerAuth": {
                "name": "Authorization",
                "in": "header",
                "type": "apiKey",
                "scheme": "bearer",
                "bearerFormat": "JWT",
                "description": "Enter your bearer token in the format Bearer <token>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### Alternatively, you can set the authorization at individual endpoints.

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.0.3",
    "info": {
        "description": "NodeJS API documentation of SSV",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "SSV APIs"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/thing": {
            "get": {
                "security": [
                    {
                        "BearerAuth": []
                    }
                ],
                "description": "Get all things",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
            "BearerAuth": {
                "name": "Authorization",
                "in": "header",
                "type": "apiKey",
                "scheme": "bearer",
                "bearerFormat": "JWT",
                "description": "Enter your bearer token in the format Bearer <token>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```